# Relations between $k, t$ and modulo $n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integers

Suppose we have $n$ people in a circle $\{0, 1, ..., n-1\}$

Also, suppose we have another person who goes around said circle and gives each of the $n$ people a gift, one each $k$ people, so:
\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathsf{\text{t}} & \mathsf{\text{Number of people}} \\\hline
0 \strut & 0 \\\hline
t_1 \strut& kt_1\mod n \\\hline
\end{array}

What would the relations be for the $n, k$ so that every person of the $n$ people get a gift? (The gift giving person has infinite gifts to give).

I have been trying to find a way to find these relations for a while now and can't conclude anything. Tips are welcome.

Comment: Try first some examples to get some feeling of the solution. For instance, try $n=4$ and $k=3$; will everybody get a gift? And what if $n=4$ and $k=6$?

Comment: If k is even and n odd (or k odd and n even) then the problem has a solution, whereas if they both are even it may fall in an infinite loop of sorts. I'm not sure what happens when both are odd, since the cases are various. 
Maybe a conclusion would be that k and n should have the greatest common divisor = 1 but I'm not sure how to prove it. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: That's right, the greatest common divisor has to be 1, i.e., the numbers must be coprimes.

Comment: Is this proven by using induction though? Testing isn't an approved method of proving (yet)

Comment: Induction is not needed (nor helpful) here.

Comment: What approach would you suggest? 
Also what about the t?
I'm sorry I'm finding it hard to comprehend furthermore

Comment: @Zap: I added an answer, please let me know if you need some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numbers are coprimes, then there is at least one integer $a$ such that:
$$a k \mod n = 1 .$$
By the way, $a$ is called the multiplicative inverse of $k$ modulo $n$.

Therefore, for all integers $j$, with $0 \leq j < n$:
$$j a k \mod n = j ,$$
Which means that at least by time $t = (n-1) a k$, everyone in the circle will have at least one present.

In fact, I believe it can be proven that at time $t = (n-1) k$ everyone will have exactly 1 present, but I'm struggling with a way to find how to prove it.

If might be helpful to take a look at some information regarding [coprime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers), and to the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).